# How to access the REST API with the user with Permission 'Is Single Sign-On Enabled' is enabled

Tags: rest, apexrest, single-sign-on, restresource

I have created one RestResourc to give the ability to the external system to attach the Report to Asset in Salesforce. Now the problem I am facing is the user which I am using for Authentication pourpose has the 'Is Single Sign-On Enabled' permission enabled so it won't allow me to generate the access token using the API.

Do you have any workaround for this? How can I use the user with the permission enabled 'Is Single Sign-On Enabled' for API Integration?

Thanks
Nirav Shah

Comment: Did you try to create a custom permission set with **API Enabled** set to true and assign this set to your user?

Comment: Yes, I have created Permission Set with the Permission 'Is Single Sign-On Enabled' as true and assigned it to the user. API Enabled is already given on Profile level

Comment: Did you check this flow ? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5 , to obtain the OAuth access token for the API you must : generate a certificate and a private key -> upload the certificate to your connected app -> Digitally sign the SSO SAML assertion returned by your identity provider using the private key after your user is logged-in -> make a POST to the token endpoint of OAuth-> Salesforce returns the access token. This flow is called Saml Bearer Assertion Flow.

Comment: Hi, @toufik_at I have uploaded the Certificate to the connected app. Now how can I Digitally sign the SSO SAML assertion? Do I need to Enable SAML in the Connected App and add Entity Id ACS URL from my Service Provider (in my case it is Okta)? What step do I need to perform

Comment: Hi @NiravShah, i may have suggested the wrong OAuth flow, i think this one is less complicated for your case : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5, check the "Exchange a SAML Assertion for an Access Token" part

Comment: Hey @toufik_at, sorry for the very late response, but your suggestion works for me. Thank you so much